# Detectar UPDATE con trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, trigger

Mi tabla de `entradas` tienes un campo `precio`, el precio se va asignado desde mi otra tabla `entrada_detalles` en automatico por trigger con `INSERT` mi problema es que si en tabla `_detalles` se modifica el precio no lo modifica en mi tabla `entrada`.
Con un trigger `DELETE` me quita el precio de la columna elimada es decir si en precio tenia 200 y elimino un detalle que proveine de esa entrada le resta perfecto con:

```
update entrada a
    join entrada_detalles di
      on di.identrada = a.id
      set a.precio = a.precio - di.precio
```

pero eso es en `DELETE` como podria hacer que detecte un `UPDATE` ?

Comment: hay triggers para update tambien. Hay algun problema en particular con ellos?

Comment: que no se como debe ir para lo que necesito :l

Comment: Pero intentaste algo? deberia ser muy parecido al del insert. Esta todo en el manual de mysql.

Comment: @ManuelMorales pudiste resolver el problema?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes crear trigger para los 3 tipos de eventos INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE

La sintaxis para crear un trigger es la siguiente

```
CREATE
    [DEFINER = { user | CURRENT_USER }]
    TRIGGER trigger_name
    { BEFORE | AFTER }  { INSERT | UPDATE | DELETE }
    ON tbl_name FOR EACH ROW
    [{ FOLLOWS | PRECEDES } other_trigger_name]
    trigger_body
```

Puedes revisar la documentación aquí: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-trigger.html

---

```
trigger_name
```

`trigger_name` representa el nombre del trigger.

---

```
{ BEFORE | AFTER }
```

Define si el trigger se ejecuta antes (BEFORE) o después del evento (AFTER), sobre cada fila.

---

```
{ INSERT | UPDATE | DELETE }
```

Define el evento que escuchará el trigger

- INSERT: Cada vez que se inserta una fila. Por ejemplo con INSERT, LOAD DATA, and REPLACE.
- UPDATE: Cada vez que se actualiza una fila con UPDATE.
- DELETE: Cada vez que se elimina una fila.por ejemplo con DELETE y REPLACE.

---

```
tbl_name
```

`tbl_name` representa el nombre de la tabla sobre la que escuchará el trigger.

---

```
 [{ FOLLOWS | PRECEDES } other_trigger_name]
```

Cuando tenemos múltiples trigger con el mismo evento y el mismo tiempo, FOLLOWS y PRECEDES nos permiten definir el orden en el que se ejecutarán.

---

```
trigger_body
```

`trigger_body` representa el cuerpo del trigger. Si necesitamos ejecutar múltiples sentencias, debemos utilizar la estructura `BEGIN ... END`. En el cuerpo del trigger podemos acceder a los datos de la sentencia con el alias NEW.nombre_col y con el alias OLD.nombre_col a los datos de la fila antes de ejecutar la sentencia.

---

> Nota: Las cascadas sobre claves foráneas no activan los trigger.